# Cmake project set LANGUAGES from variable

Tags: c++, objective-c, cmake

currently I've got the following project definition :

```
set(supported_languages "CXX OBJC OBJCXX")

project(
  myProj
  VERSION ${ver}
  LANGUAGES ${supported_languages})
```

where `supported_languages` is defined as string of parameters delimited by space
(i.e. `CXX OBJC OBJCXX`)

However, it fails since cmake expect to get a list and this is the error I get

```
CMake Error: Could not find cmake module file: CMakeDetermineCXX OBJC OBJCXXCompiler.cmake
```

So I've tried to convert it to list `list(${supported_languages})` but it still doesn't work.

I wonder what is the best practice to make it work ?

Comment: Offtopic: what is rationale to have list of languages in separate variable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that error is because (") characterer
lets try this

```
set(supported_languages CXX OBJC OBJCXX)

project(
  myProj
  VERSION ${ver}
  LANGUAGES ${supported_languages})
```

Comment: Sounds good, but what if i want to append items to `supported_languages` ? perhaps you can extend your example with appending additional values ?

Comment: unfortunately, I tried with passing argument method but it don't work, cmake have some type of variable and none of them help to resolve extending like you want, . https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/set.html